# SequenceAlignment behavior

Tags: string-manipulation

When I do:

```
SequenceAlignment["-0.999995756767227832383453368554576431549","-0.999995756767227832383346049698547342279"]
```

I get:

```
{-0.99999575676722783238,{,3},34,{533,6049},6,{,9},8,{5,},54,{5,},7,{6,3},4,{3154,227},9}
```

Clearly there is an extra 3 that is missing as a common sequence number at the end:

```
-0.9999957567672278323834...
-0.9999957567672278323833...
```

Is this a bug? (Using Mathematica 10.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica took the alignments in the following way

```
-0.99999575676722783238x34
-0.99999575676722783238334
```

Comment: Yes, but why this behavior?

Comment: @Giovanni Well, I haven't checked the details but it's using the [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought it was an exact method of finding these sequences.

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the `GapPenalty" (default is zero) you can pick up the 3; however, the difference sequences get longer and the total similarity score decreases.

```
SequenceAlignment["-0.999995756767227832383453368554576431549", \
"-0.999995756767227832383346049698547342279", GapPenalty -> 3]
```

> {"-0.999995756767227832383", {"453368554", "346049698"}, "5",
>   {"7643154",    "4734227"}, "9"}